# flutter video_player when closing the app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-video-player

The homepage consists of list of videos which play from the network.and only the video in the main screen starts playing. i am disposing the videocontroller.
I have the popup dialog in my app, when the user goes back to close the app, and clicking on exit is giving me some errors in log.

```
    E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 8166): Video codec error
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 8166):   java.lang.IllegalStateException
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 8166):       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_dequeueInputBuffer(Native Method)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 8166):       at android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2855)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.dequeueInputBufferIndex(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:93)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.feedInputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1209)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:845)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:945)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:478)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 8166):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 8166):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer( 8166):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.64001F, -1, null, [540, 960, 25.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:555)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoDecoderException: Decoder failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.createDecoderException(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:1410)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:864)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:945)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:478)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       ... 3 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_dequeueInputBuffer(Native Method)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2855)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.dequeueInputBufferIndex(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:93)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.feedInputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1209)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:845)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       ... 5 more
E/VideoFrameReleaseHelper( 8166): Failed to call Surface.setFrameRate
E/VideoFrameReleaseHelper( 8166):   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Surface has already been released.
E/VideoFrameReleaseHelper( 8166):       at android.view.Surface.checkNotReleasedLocked(Surface.java:696)
E/VideoFrameReleaseHelper( 8166):       at android.view.Surface.setFrameRate(Surface.java:905)
E/VideoFrameReleaseHelper( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.VideoFrameReleaseHelper.setSurfaceFrameRateV30(VideoFrameReleaseHelper.java:389)
E/VideoFrameReleaseHelper( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.VideoFrameReleaseHelper.clearSurfaceFrameRate(VideoFrameReleaseHelper.java:379)
E/VideoFrameReleaseHelper( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.VideoFrameReleaseHelper.onStopped(VideoFrameReleaseHelper.java:232)
E/VideoFrameReleaseHelper( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onStopped(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:471)
E/VideoFrameReleaseHelper( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.BaseRenderer.stop(BaseRenderer.java:165)
E/VideoFrameReleaseHelper( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.ensureStopped(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1599)
E/VideoFrameReleaseHelper( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.disableRenderer(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1608)
E/VideoFrameReleaseHelper( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.resetInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1351)
E/VideoFrameReleaseHelper( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.stopInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1314)
E/VideoFrameReleaseHelper( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:571)
E/VideoFrameReleaseHelper( 8166):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/VideoFrameReleaseHelper( 8166):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/VideoFrameReleaseHelper( 8166):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166): Disable failed.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):   java.lang.IllegalStateException
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_flush(Native Method)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at android.media.MediaCodec.flush(MediaCodec.java:2298)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.flush(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:160)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.flushCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:912)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.flushOrReleaseCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:905)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onDisabled(MediaCodecRenderer.java:761)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onDisabled(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:483)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.BaseRenderer.disable(BaseRenderer.java:176)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.disableRenderer(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1609)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.resetInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1351)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.stopInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1314)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:571)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8166):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

i do not know how to solve this problem.

Comment: are you using only `video_player` or you are also using `chewie` also the you have to dispose both

Comment: only video_player plugin